# Unable to change mobile browser address bar color for wp-login.php

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Dears,

I know this might be a little silly for majority of you but I try different options and nothing works - I added following function to my WordPress page to change mobile browser address bar and it does the work for every page except wp-login.php

```
function address_bar_color() {
    echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'address_bar_color' );
```

Tried different methods to see if I'm doing everything right - like installing the plugins etc. and nothing works. Does any of you have any clue what could be the reason?

I'll be really grateful for your help. Thank you!

I tried to install different plugins, also tried code but it does not work for wp-login.php page:

```
function address_bar_color() {
    echo '<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'address_bar_color' );
```